# Sitecore Publishing.DisableDatabaseCaches Setting On a Content Delivery (CD) Server

Tags: publishing, caching, content-delivery

### Does `<setting name="Publishing.DisableDatabaseCaches" value="true"/>` have any effect at all on a CD server?

I understand that the CM, which is the publishing server, would be affected by this setting as it's doing the publish operation. However, I'm wondering if the CD server does *something* when it "receives" the published content that might utilise this setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In default Sitecore installation, this settings is not even used. `Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.OverridePublishContext` processor overrides it anyway. It's only when this processor is disabled, the settings is used. But even then, only the publishing server is affected.

From what I know, CD server does not "receive" the published context, it only receives remote events related to publishing.

Just so it's more clear, here is the comment from config file for `OverridePublishContext` processor:

```
<!--
 This processor overrides the DisableDatabaseCaches and the MaxDegreeOfParallelism properties of the PublishContext class.

 The DisableDatabaseCaches property of the PublishContext is overridden and set to true if child items are being published,
 including when you perform a full site publish.
 If only a single item is being published, the property is set to false.
 If you disable this processor, the publish context uses the value of the Publishing.DisableDatabaseCaches setting for all the
 publishing operations.

 If only a single item is being published, the MaxDegreeOfParallelism property of the PublishContext is overridden to 1.
 This disables parallel publishing for single item publishing operations. 
-->
<processor type="Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.OverridePublishContext, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I suspected. It's this part that still sparks my curiosity: `it only receives remote events related to publishing.`. What happens when it receives those events? Presumably it does some action/pipeline/method/thing with the new items in the database. I wonder if, in doing that, it reads the new items and potentially adds that item into the cache.

If that happened, based on your answer, I would not expect Sitecore to use this setting but is there a way of confirming this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I won't be able to help you with that question. From what I remember events like `item:saved:remote` and `publish:end:remote` are called when item is published. But you would need to dig a bit deeper to confirm if this setting has any impact on the logic executed by those events.